# command in windows batch file copying some folders while starting a Slack app

Tags: windows, batch-file, slack

I wrote a small batch command

```
START "" "C:\Users\Doniyor\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\slack.exe"
```

this command starts the [Slack](https://slack.com/) app but also copies these folders to my Desktop:

```
logs
temp
redux-state (json file)
```

am I doing something wrong in batch command? how can I make it only start the app and not copy anything anywhere?

Comment: Presumably slack is creating these directories in the current directory when it starts and the batch file is on the desktop. Modify your batch file to change to an appropriate directory before running slack.